# Help interpreting a nested PERMANOVA model required

Tags: biostatistics, ecology, nested-models

My study looks into the effects of fishing on the ecological community.
There are n=4 sites in a marine reserve and the adjacent fished area.
The ecological community was sporadically sampled every 1-3 years for 20 years (overall, n=10 years).

My design is: 'year' and 'status' (i.e. reserve vs. fished) - fixed factors, 'site (status)' - random.

However I found a similar study that used 'site (year, status)' - random, instead.

I'm having trouble to wrap my head around nesting year in site, because the same sites are sampled every year in reserve vs. fished areas.

Which design is more accurate?
Please explain